# Using html tag in php

Tags: php, html

```
myfile = mysql_query($query_myfile, $db) or die(mysql_error());
$totalRows_myfile = mysql_num_rows($myfile);
$typ_d = '';
$test='';


while ( $row_myfile = mysql_fetch_assoc($myfile) ) 
{
   if ( $typ_d != $row_myfile[ 'typ_d' ] ) 
   {

       $typ_d = $row_myfile[ 'typ_d' ];

       echo "<h2>$typ_d</h2>";

   }
   if ( $test != $row_myfile[ 'test' ] ) 
   {

       $test = $row_myfile[ 'test' ];

       echo "<h3>$test</h3>";
   }

   echo "<li><a href=\"myfileDetail.php?myfile_id=".$row_myfile['myfile_id']. "\">";
   echo $row_myfile['shortname'].' ';
   echo $row_myfile['name']; ?></a></li>

   <?php } ?>
```

how can I use `<ul>` tag to have the result like this.I want to have each $test elements to be enclosed in `<ul> </ul>`

```
first groups
<ul>
          <li>Coffee</li>
          <li>Tea</li>
          <li>Milk</li>
        </ul>

    second groups
<ul>
          <li>Coffee</li>
          <li>Tea</li>
          <li>Milk</li>
        </ul>
    .
    .
    .
```

Comment: Please explain where `Tea` `Coffe` `Milk` are coming from and how they relate to you code above.

Comment: I just wanted to show example they are not related

Comment: You loop only generates one `<li>` per iteration - how do you decide where the `<ul>` break will go?

Comment: I want to have it @  $test = $row_myfile[ 'test' ]; because it a group

Comment: Without being an a-hole can I just suggest that if you don't have a firm grasp on basic programming concepts like loops, array indexes and echo statements you might be better served browsing some online tutorials rather than posting on stack overflow.

Comment: Agreed with @rdlowrey. http://www.codecademy.com/ might be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

```
$myfile = mysql_query($query_myfile, $db) or die(mysql_error());
$totalRows_myfile = mysql_num_rows($myfile);
$typ_d = '';
$test = '';

while ( $row_myfile = mysql_fetch_assoc($myfile) ) {
   if ( $typ_d != $row_myfile[ 'typ_d' ] ) {
     $typ_d = $row_myfile[ 'typ_d' ];
     echo "<h2>$typ_d</h2><ul>";
   }
   if ( $test != $row_myfile[ 'test' ] ) {
     $test = $row_myfile[ 'test' ];
     echo "</ul><h3>$test</h3><ul>";
   }
   echo "<li><a href=\"myfileDetail.php?myfile_id={$row_myfile['myfile_id']}\">{$row_myfile['shortname']} {$row_myfile['name']}</a></li>";
}

echo "</ul>";
```

That is my best guess at what you want.

Comment: hi dave thanx!  it appears empty <ul></ul (they contain no list elements) some out groups of lists together.. i cannot really find the problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each "group" is one sql statement, then the below will work.

```
<?php
myfile = mysql_query($query_myfile, $db) or die(mysql_error());
$totalRows_myfile = mysql_num_rows($myfile);
$typ_d = '';
$test='';

$i = 0;
while ( $row_myfile = mysql_fetch_assoc($myfile) ) 
{
$i++;
   if ( $typ_d != $row_myfile[ 'typ_d' ] ) 
   {

       $typ_d = $row_myfile[ 'typ_d' ];

       echo "<h2>$typ_d</h2>";

   }
   if ( $test != $row_myfile[ 'test' ] ) 
   {

       $test = $row_myfile[ 'test' ];

       echo "<h3>$test</h3>";
   }

   if ($i == 1) {
   echo '<ul>';
   }
   echo "<li><a href=\"myfileDetail.php?myfile_id=".$row_myfile['myfile_id']. "\">";
   echo $row_myfile['shortname'].' ';
   echo $row_myfile['name'].'</a></li>'
   if ($i == $totalRows_myfile) {
   echo '</ul>';
   }
   } ?>
```

All your needing to do is output `<ul>` before your list items (on the first instance of the while loop), and `</ul>` after the list items (on the last instance of the while loop).

If each group is however not one sql statement, then you'll need to end and start the ul tags accordingly.

Comment: Thank !I tried to use it but am getting<ul> at the beginning of the first group list and </ul> at the end of the last group list. normally it should be at start and end of every group

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to do, but if you want to generate different lists based on a condition inside the loop, you need to group your data first and only `echo` it when your done.